# How to Asynchronously add a list of Documents to an Appengine Search API Index?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search-api

I am experimenting with Appengine (python) [SearchAPI](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/indexclass). I have created a list of documents and am correctly adding this list of documents to the Search API Index. It works great, but my code has to wait for this to happen (synchronously).

My business logic would allow this to happen asynchronously and I was wondering if anybody out there has some recommendations on how I might add this synchronously (similar to some other appengine python tricks like put_async).

Code:

```
try:        
    search.Index(name=free_text_index).add(documents)
except search.Error:
    logging.exception("Add to Free Text Index " + free_text_index + " failed")
```

Looking for something to allow something like this (or recommendations on something that would have the same effect).

I'm looking for something like the put_async command.

```
myobject.put_async()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python Search API doesn't currently support async calls.  I suggest you use Task Queue to do async adding of documents.

Comment: Peter, thanks much for the quick response. I'll go that route for the time being - it should work. The only issue that *may* come up may be how quick this gets into the search index (as a user may want to search shortly after that request is made). I'll brush up on task queues. Thanks again.